# How can I unload a servlet in its init() method? Can I unload it in the servlet constructor?

Tags: servlets

How can I unload a servlet from its container using the servlet's constructor or init() method?

If I unload it using the servlet constructor, will the init() method still be called?
Should I throw an exception?  If so, checked or runtime?

Comment: What do you mean by "unload?" What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want container to unload servlet so that if I hit it with URL i should get unavailable error .

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't dynamically remove/unload servlets. You _can_ add/load them using [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) methods. Why can't you just comment out parts of web.xml, or comment out `@WebServlet` annotations, and then redeploy?

Comment: what will happen if I call destroy method ?? will it be unloaded or just method will be called on object

Comment: `destroy()` is for the container to call, not you. It's not magic, it's just a way for you to hook into the servlet's lifecycle. So, as you say, if you call `destroy()`, you're just calling a method on the object, nothing more.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html and http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing an exception in the servlet's constructor or `init()` method will prevent it from being taken in the servlet mapping of the servletcontainer.

You can not unload it at a later time when it has already been constructed and initialized successfully. Best what you can do is to just throw an exception in any of the HTTP methods based on some condition.

The right approach however depends on the sole functional requirement. Most probably you do not need a servlet at all. Simply because the desire to unload it manually makes design technically no utter sense.

Answer (score 0):

if we call destroy() on servlet then it doesn't mean that our servlet will be unloaded/destroyed. It simply calls destroy leaving servlet untouched, nothing harm to servlet instance. It is still alive because you called destroy method. It is not container mechanism which is calling destroy method.

when container decides to destroy/unload the servlet instance from memory then container runs destruction mechanism and destroy method is one(along with several steps) of steps of the destruction mechanism. Destruction mechanism give chance to user/developer to clean-up resources which were initialized during the construction/initializing of the instance.